Cant display separate NIfTI files to several containers using papaya js inside next js page/component
I would like to display several NIfTI file using papaya js in one page inside next js. However, upon initializing it, only one of containers with component instance containing papaya js gets shown with the "params" image inserted and unpacked. enter image description here
I tried to make copies of the component containing papaya js, down is one of the examples, they are all same except for name of function
"use client";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import React from "react";

declare global {
  interface Window {
    papaya: any;
  }
}

export default function Display2dSwi({ imageUrl }: { imageUrl: string | null }) {
  const papayaContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadScripts = async () => {
      try {
        // Ensure styles are loaded first
        const papayaStyles = document.createElement("link");
        papayaStyles.href = "/papaya.css";
        papayaStyles.rel = "stylesheet";
        document.head.appendChild(papayaStyles);

        // Load Font Awesome
        const fontAwesomeStyles = document.createElement("link");
        fontAwesomeStyles.href =
          "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css";
        fontAwesomeStyles.rel = "stylesheet";
        document.head.appendChild(fontAwesomeStyles);

        // Load jQuery first
        const jqueryScript = document.createElement("script");
        jqueryScript.src =
          "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js";
        jqueryScript.type = "text/javascript";
        jqueryScript.async = true;
        jqueryScript.onload = () => {
          console.log("jQuery loaded successfully");

          // Load Papaya.js after jQuery
          const papayaScript = document.createElement("script");
          papayaScript.src = "/papaya1.js";
          papayaScript.type = "text/javascript";
          papayaScript.async = true;
          papayaScript.onload = () => {
            console.log("Papaya.js loaded successfully");
            initializePapaya();
          };
          papayaScript.onerror = (err) => {
            console.error("Error loading Papaya.js:", err);
          };
          document.body.appendChild(papayaScript);
        };
        jqueryScript.onerror = (err) => {
          console.error("Error loading jQuery:", err);
        };
        document.body.appendChild(jqueryScript);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error loading scripts or styles:", error);
      }
    };

    const initializePapaya = () => {
      if (typeof window.papaya !== "undefined") {
        if (papayaContainerRef.current) {
          const containerId = `papaya-container-${Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9)}`;
          papayaContainerRef.current.id = containerId;
          papayaContainerRef.current.setAttribute(
            "data-params",
            JSON.stringify({
              images: [imageUrl],
              expandable: true,
            })
          );

          window.papaya.Container.startPapaya();
          console.log("Papaya 1 initialized with imageUrl:", imageUrl);

        }
      } else {
        console.error("Papaya is not defined");
      }
    };

    loadScripts();
  }, [imageUrl]);

  return <div ref={papayaContainerRef} className="papaya"></div>;
}

Then I put its instance inside another main component/page

  return (
    <>
      <Breadcrumb items={items} />
      <div className="flex justify-center items-start h-full bg-[#212D48] pt-8">
        <div className="flex flex-col items-start max-w-6xl w-full mt-4">
          <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
            <ArrowLeftOutlined
              className="text-6xl cursor-pointer text-[#736A6A]"
              style={{ color: "#736A6A", paddingBottom: "100px" }}
              onClick={() => router.push("/scanner")}
            />
            <Card
              title="Name:"
              className="w-64 rounded-none"
              bordered={false}
              style={{ background: "#5147CE", color: "white" }}
            >
              <p>Height: 180 cm</p>
              <p>Sex: Male</p>
              <p>Blood Type: O+</p>
            </Card>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-between w-full mt-8">
            <div className="flex space-x-4">
              <div className="flex flex-col w-auto h-auto">
                <h3 className="text-white mb-2">Title 1</h3>
                <Display2dPd
                  imageUrl={
                    "/pd_test.gz"
                  }
                />
              </div>
              <div className="flex flex-col w-auto h-auto">
                <h3 className="text-white mb-2">Title 2</h3>
                <Display2dT1
                  imageUrl={
                    "/uploaded.nii.gz"
                  }
                />
              </div>
              <div className="flex flex-col w-auto h-auto">
                <h3 className="text-white mb-2">Title 3</h3>
                <Display2dSwi
                  imageUrl={
                    "/uploaded.nii.gz"
                  }
                />
              </div>


I think you can only call startPapaya() once.  Look at the function in main.js to get a better idea how it works.  See tests/debug_server_nested.html for an example of how to use multiple instances on the same page.
